# Alternate header image

Tags: themes, images, design

Is there a convenient and configurable way to alternate between different header images?

The main features I'm looking for are:

- Random select from a set of images
- Specific header image in given date range (a la [Google Doodle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_logo#Google_Doodle))
- Specific header image for specific posts or pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

**Random from a set of images :**

```
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/image_<?php echo rand(1,10); ?>.jpg" alt="" />
```

This would load a random image from image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg ... to image_10.jpg

or

```
$images = array("cool_image.jpg", "nice_pic.jpg", "sunset.jpg");
$rand = array_rand($images);

<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/<?php echo $images[$rand]; ?>" alt="" />
```

This would select a randow image from thoses specified in the $images array.

**Date range :**

```
<?php
if ((date('m') == 3) && (date('d') == 17)) { ?>
    <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/stpatrick.jpg" alt="" />
<?php } ?>
```

This would show an image for St Patricks

**Specific posts or pages :**

See : [Change image based on menu item id](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19582/change-image-based-on-menu-item-id/19583#19583)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. These lines should replace the existing one in header.php, right?

Comment: @Adam Matan, If there is already a `<img />` in your `header.php` then yes that's the one you would replace.